# Custom python sort

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a python dataframe (assume as df) where the column having following data:

[image]

I need to sort this data in this order:

[image]

I can sort this by df.sort_values() however this will not sort the data in required format. Any help please... I am using python 3.10

Comment: Are you looking for a general solution, or just for these 7 values only?

Comment: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](//stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/843953) Please don't post screenshots of text.

Answer (score 1):

One simple solution is to create a dict like `d = {'<=1x':0,'1x-5x':1,...}` and then create a new column by mapping the old to new using this dict: `df['new'] = df['old'].map(d)`, and finally sort on this new column: `df.sort_values('new')`

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to map each string to a tuple containing the lower and upper bounds of your range. For example, `<=1x` maps to `(-inf, 1.0)`, `1x-5x` maps to `(1.0, 5.0)`, and so on, so that `sort_values()` can sort them for you.

You can do this using a regex:

```
import re
def convert_range(r):
    rng = re.findall(r"(-?\d+\.?\d*)x-(-?\d+\.?\d*)x", r)

    if rng: # rng is not empty 
        rng = rng[0] # So set rng to the first result of findall()
    else:
        if "<" in r:
            nums = re.findall(r"<=?(-?\d+\.?\d*)x", r)
            rng = ['-inf', nums[0]]
        elif ">" in r:
            nums = re.findall(r">=?(-?\d+\.?\d*)x", r)
            rng = [nums[0], 'inf']

    return tuple(float(r) for r in rng) # Convert elements of rng to float
```

So say you have the following dataframe:

```
     ranges
0    5x-10x
1  50x-100x
2   20x-50x
3   10x-20x
4     >100x
5      <=1x
```

You'd do:

```
df['tup_ranges'] = df['ranges'].apply(convert_range)
df = df.sort_values(by=['tup_ranges'])
```

which gives:

```
     ranges     tup_ranges
5      <=1x    (-inf, 1.0)
0    5x-10x    (5.0, 10.0)
3   10x-20x   (10.0, 20.0)
2   20x-50x   (20.0, 50.0)
1  50x-100x  (50.0, 100.0)
4     >100x   (100.0, inf)
```

Comment: I understand what logic you want to use, however what parameter I need to pass here, how to call this function, I have a dataframe which has this columns

Comment: I am getting following error with this solution
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a real number, not 'tuple'

Comment: @deepankarsrigyan I fixed it. Try now.